# Execution of Inference Workloads on Coral Dev Board in CPU, GPU and TPU simultaneously

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-coral

I am currently working on executing inference workloads on Coral Dev Board with TensorFlow Lite. I am trying to run inference on CPU,GPU and TPU simultaneously to reduce inference latency.

Could you guys help me understand how I can execute inference on all the devices simultaneously? I could divide the layers of network for training phase in CPU and GPU but I am having trouble in assigning layers of the network to each devices for inference.The code is written in python language with keras API in Tensorflow.

Thanks.

Comment: I think its much better if you show your code, we can't really guess

Answer (score 0):

As of now, if you compile your CPU TFLite model with the edgeTPU compiler (https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/) then the compiler tries to Map the operations on the TPU only (as long as the operations are supported by the TPU)

The Edge TPU compiler cannot partition the model more than once, and as soon as an unsupported operation occurs, that operation and everything after it executes on the CPU, even if supported operations occur later.

So partitioning a single TFLite model into CPU, GPU and TPU is not feasible as of now.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could you please help me know, if it is feasible to split layers amongst CPU and GPU in HiKey970 board? Do you have any suggestions on how it can be done with Tensorflow or any other tools?